How to successfully patch openSSL?
I have a computer with unix and an old binary version of OpenSSL installed (version 1.0.2h). I came across the link below:
https://github.com/cloudflare/sslconfig/tree/master
and it suggests I could patch my openSSL so I could have the  ChaCha20/Poly1305 cipher enabled.
I don't know exactly how to do this.
I tried executing:
patch < openssl__chacha20_poly1305_draft_and_rfc_ossl102g.patch

because I think its for OpenSSL 1.0.2g which is 1 letter below my version.
I received the following result:
can't find file to patch at input line 48
Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|From d21c75c622eb13a80080ed15fa30474f806a0a0f Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
|From: Vlad Krasnov <vlad@cloudflare.com>
|Date: Fri, 12 Feb 2016 18:25:11 -0800
|Subject: [PATCH] Implementation of draft and RFC versions of CHACHA20-POLY1305
| ciphers
|
|---
| Configure                                    |  48 +-
| Makefile.org                                 |   4 +-
| apps/speed.c                                 |  30 +-
| crypto/chacha20poly1305/Makefile             |  97 +++
| crypto/chacha20poly1305/asm/chacha20_avx.pl  | 408 +++++++++++
| crypto/chacha20poly1305/asm/chacha20_avx2.pl | 443 ++++++++++++
| crypto/chacha20poly1305/asm/poly1305_avx.pl  | 732 ++++++++++++++++++++
| crypto/chacha20poly1305/asm/poly1305_avx2.pl | 984 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| crypto/chacha20poly1305/asm/poly1305_x64.pl  | 281 ++++++++
| crypto/chacha20poly1305/chacha20.c           | 162 +++++
| crypto/chacha20poly1305/chacha20poly1305.h   |  79 +++
| crypto/chacha20poly1305/chapolytest.c        | 470 +++++++++++++
| crypto/chacha20poly1305/poly1305.c           | 287 ++++++++
| crypto/cryptlib.c                            |  10 -
| crypto/evp/Makefile                          |   7 +-
| crypto/evp/e_chacha20poly1305.c              | 435 ++++++++++++
| crypto/evp/evp.h                             |   4 +
| ssl/s3_lib.c                                 | 119 ++++
| ssl/ssl.h                                    |   2 +
| ssl/ssl_ciph.c                               |  60 +-
| ssl/ssl_locl.h                               |   2 +
| ssl/tls1.h                                   |  28 +
| test/Makefile                                |  17 +-
| 23 files changed, 4655 insertions(+), 54 deletions(-)
| create mode 100644 crypto/chacha20poly1305/Makefile
| create mode 100644 crypto/chacha20poly1305/asm/chacha20_avx.pl
| create mode 100644 crypto/chacha20poly1305/asm/chacha20_avx2.pl
| create mode 100644 crypto/chacha20poly1305/asm/poly1305_avx.pl
| create mode 100644 crypto/chacha20poly1305/asm/poly1305_avx2.pl
| create mode 100644 crypto/chacha20poly1305/asm/poly1305_x64.pl
| create mode 100644 crypto/chacha20poly1305/chacha20.c
| create mode 100644 crypto/chacha20poly1305/chacha20poly1305.h
| create mode 100644 crypto/chacha20poly1305/chapolytest.c
| create mode 100644 crypto/chacha20poly1305/poly1305.c
| create mode 100644 crypto/evp/e_chacha20poly1305.c
|
|diff --git a/Configure b/Configure
|index 4a715dc..f3ab6cd 100755
|--- a/Configure
|+++ b/Configure
--------------------------

Then it asks me the file to patch.
What should I type in?

This is a source code patch, not a binary patch. You will need to get the source code for version 1.0.2g, apply the patch and compile.
